# Recuperar cliente y una sola direccion de una API mediante Odata

Tags: api, filtro, odata

Estoy consumiendo una API con **Odata** y me he encontrado con un problema que no puedo resolver.
Necesito consultar una entidad **Customer** y traerme su dirección, los **customers** pueden tener múltiples direcciones y solo quiero traerme la dirección '0'.
El problema es que el campo que identifica la dirección, viene como una subentidad de esta **(extendedProperties)** dejo aquí la estructura:

```
{
      "Id": "86f420e3-27d6-4491-8792-85d15655218d",
      "Name": "Customer 1",
      "Email": "c1@business.info",
      "Phone": "555234345",
      "BusinessName": "C1",
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "ExtendedProperties": [
            {
              "Id": "NumeroDomicilio",
              "Value": "0"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "86f420e3-27d6-4491-8792-85d15655218d",
          "FullAddress": "Domicilio 1",
          "Street": "",
          "Number": ""
        },
        {
          "ExtendedProperties": [
            {
              "Id": "NumeroDomicilio",
              "Value": "1"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "8b1d1586-1621-4e12-89ee-344154041450",
          "FullAddress": "C/ Ferro",
          "Street": "",
          "Number": ""
        },
        {
          "ExtendedProperties": [
            {
              "Id": "NumeroDomicilio",
              "Value": "2"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "dc0fb5bf-e72a-468c-9602-efe3919c693e",
          "FullAddress": "Domicili 2",
          "Street": "",
          "Number": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Como he dicho, solo quiero traerme la dirección que tenga en su extendedproperties la propiedad *Value = '0'*.
Leyendo la documentación de **Odata**, veo que la mejor manera de hacerlo sería:

> /Customers?$expand=addresses($filter=extendedproperties/any(prop:
> prop/Value eq '0'))
> Esto no me da error, pero me devuelve el cliente sin ninguna dirección.
> ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?
> Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu no quieres filtrar la consulta, quieres filtrar el resultado, es decir el select.

La mejor opción es que el cliente filtre los datos, no veo motivo para complicar el asunto.

La otra alternativa es que empieces tu consulta a la inversa, es decir desde ExtendedProperties

*Nota: Value es 0 o '0' (int o string)???*

Algo así:

```
/ExtendedProperties?$filter(Value eq '0')&$expand=Addresses($expand=Customers)
```

Aquí habría que jugar un poco con el select para dejar lo más parecido posible a tu salida, aunque creo que no podrá exactamente.

Lamentablemente la única solución a mí se me ocurre es aplicar el filter en el select, de esta manera:

```
/Customers?$expand=addresses($expand=ExtendedProperties)&$select Id,Name,Email,Phone,BusinessName, Addresses($filter=ExtendedProperties/Value eq '0')
```

Que según [esto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/nested-query-options-in-select) es válido, pero a mí no me ha resultado nunca

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Yussef, pero no es lo que necesito, el segundo filtro no funciona, el primero si, el problema es que ese filtro me retorna todas las direcciones, ya que lo que filtra es su entidad hija ExtendedProperties, lo que necesito es que no me retorne la dirección si en su ExtendedProperties el valor de Value es 0.

Comment: Ya probé de poner el filtro en la select y nada, creo que al final la solución será la que ambos tememos, filtrar en el resultado.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal no se con que lenguaje estas programando pero en c# yo uso:

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

con este namespace puedo obetener de es json la propiedad que mencionas de la siguiente manera:

```
public static string GetNode(string NameProperty)
    {
        var jsonBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("objetoJs.json");

        var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonBytes);

        var jsonString = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty(NameProperty).ToString();

        return jsonString ;
    }
```

Con este codigo puedo leer un archivo `.json` e indicarle en el `StringName` el nombre de la propiedad la cual quiero acceder.
Deberías ver en tu lenguaje como deserealizar un fichero `.json`.

Tambien podrias deserealizar a un objeto concreto que reciba esa lista:

```
public static List<T> GetListProperty<T>(string PropertyName)
    {
        var jsonBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("objetoJs.json");

        List<T> myList = new List<T>();

        var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonBytes);

        var myString = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty(PropertyName);

        try
        {
            // Si la propiedad es un array o lista.
            if (myString.ValueKind.ToString() == "Array")
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < myString.GetArrayLength(); i++)
                {
                    // Si el array es un objeto.
                    if (myString[i].ValueKind.ToString() == "Object")
                    {
                        var parse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(myString[i].ToString());
                        myList.Add(parse);
                    }
                    // En caso de ser un array simple
                    else
                    {
                        var oj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(myString[i].ToString());
                        myList.Add(oj);
                    }

                }
                return myList.ToList();
            }
            else
                return default(List<T>);
        }
        catch(JsonException jsex)
        {
            throw new Exception(jsex.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

Yo estoy con c#5 `.netCore`
Ojala pueda serte de ayuda, pero el truco esta en conocer tu lenguaje y como interactuar con Json, un saludo...

Comment: Hola, antes de responder puedes preguntar al OP sobre que lenguaje usa, saludos.

Comment: Hola @Marco ahora mismo, el lenguaje es irrelevante, ya que lo que estoy es construyendo el filtro y las pruebas las hago desde postman una vez me funcione el filtro, entonces sí que desarrollaré la lógica para su consumo, pero ahora mismo necesito antes poder filtrar las direcciones.